# SQL: convert string to datetime in Sybase IQ

Tags: sql, sap-iq

I am trying to convert a string into a datetime in Sybase IQ. The string has this form: '20191211 11:49:00.565224 +0700'

I first try with `Convert DATETIME`:
the following 2 queries fail:

```
SELECT CONVERT("DATETIME", '20191211 16:29:56.226560 +0000', 112) AS "TIME_dt"
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '20191211 16:29:56.226560 +0000', 112) AS "TIME_dt"
```

However, when used in a query like

```
SELECT CONVERT("DATETIME", "TIME_", 112) AS "TIME_dt" FROM TABLE
```

and the column "TIME_" contains `'20191211 16:29:56.226560 +0000'` then I get the result: `2019-12-11 00:00:00` and it correctly transformed `20191211` to `2019-12-11`

Next I try with `SELECT CONVERT( DATETIMEOFFSET , '20191211 11:49:00.565224 +0700')` and that works, but when I use it in a query like

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIMEOFFSET, "TIME_") AS "TIME_dt" FROM TABLE
```

I get an error with :

```
[Code: 21, SQL State: QFA2A]  SQL Anywhere Error -1001030: Feature, Cast to Unknown TypeID (29) at line 1, is not supported. 
-- (dflib/df_Heap.cxx 6835)
```

What is going on?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had a look at https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_convert.asp, basically, the third parameter is optional, in your case `112`, it tells you exactly the format, that's why you are getting the formatting error, because it's missing `112`. The other error has to do with how to pass the variable, what you are actually passing, a string or a date value.

Comment: I need it to read the offset. DATETIME while works, does not deal with the offset correctly. DATETIMEOFFSET deals with the offset, but fails when used in a table.